# Replace Django Admin Login page

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

I need to replace the Django Admin Login page. The reason for that is that I've added some extra authentication at my own login page, however, I don't know how to override the login on the admin site.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution. Inside `urls.py`, add the path to the new login page above your admin URLs like this

```
path('admin/login/', login_view, name='new_admin_login'),  # login_view is the custom login view
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom `AdminSite` is the Django way of doing such things. Specifically, in your case set the [**`AdminSite.login_form`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.login_form)

```py
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.urls import path


class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    # override the methods you want
    ...


class CustomAdminSite(AdminSite):
    login_form = CustomAuthenticationForm


admin_site = CustomAdminSite()

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin_site.urls),
]
```

Comment: It's not just the form. I've added PGP 2fa on my login page. That's why I thought of using that login and completely replacing the admin login